# SharePoint Online Federated Results in Query Rule Results Block

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search, query-rule

We have an on-premise SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Search platform. We have a SharePoint Online tenant which federates results to my search site. I would like to display a results block from the federated results in my enterprise search site but am unable to get results. Is this a possibility or we can only get result block to display results from local index and not federated results?